# How to add the result of 2 functions together and add result to div in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I've two functions that return an integer `finSum()` and `getTotal()`.

How do I sum the result and send it to `<div class="grandTotal"></div>` using something like `$(".grandTotal").text(somevalue);`.

Comment: is that what you mean? ```$(".grandTotal").text(finSum()+getTotal());```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the two returned values together:

```
var somevalue = finSum() + getTotal();

$(".grandTotal").text(somevalue);
```

Comment: For some reason it just won't inject the value into that div. Should it be placed inside/outside a function or at the bottom of the document.ready? See the whole script at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68785705/adding-a-returned-value-from-a-function-to-a-document-ready-function-and-outp?noredirect=1#comment121565516_68785705 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions provide an implicit return: values are returned without the usage of the return keyword.

You can use template literals to show your result on `div`.

Here is a full example using arrow function and template literals.

```js
let a = 2,
    b = 3,
    c = 4,
    d = 5

const finSum = () => a + b;
const getTotal = () => c + d;
const grandTotal = () => finSum() + getTotal();

let html = `<span>Gand Total: ${grandTotal()}</span>`;
$('.grandTotal').html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grandTotal">
</div>
```